# Jena: property name cannot be resolved to a variable?

Tags: rdf, jena, ontology, protege

I'm using Jena to query my ontology, and I'm following *Step 8: Querying a Model* of [this tutorial](http://jena.sourceforge.net/tutorial/RDF_API/). The RDF file *vc-db-1.rdf* being queried here is generated from *Step 3: Writing RDF* and is shown below:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:vcard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A0">
    <vcard:Family>Smith</vcard:Family>
    <vcard:Given>John</vcard:Given>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/JohnSmith">
    <vcard:N rdf:nodeID="A0"/>
    <vcard:FN>John Smith</vcard:FN>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The sample code is *tutorial 7* and can be downloaded [here](http://jena.sourceforge.net/src-examples/jena/examples/rdf/Tutorial07.java).

I noticed that in the line

```
ResIterator iter = model.listResourcesWithProperty(VCARD.FN);
```

*VCARD.FN* is only a property name from the RDF, but not a defined variable in my code. However, it can be successfully recognized here and the code runs without any problem.

But this is not the case with my own RDF file. I created an ontology *pottery.owl* with Protege and saved it in RDF/XML language. The file content is as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:protege="http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/protege#"
    xmlns:xsp="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/2005/08/07/xsp.owl#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:swrl="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#"
    xmlns="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1369190090.owl#"
    xmlns:swrlb="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xml:base="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1369190090.owl" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="#pottery">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="#pottery_instance_1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="#pottery"/>
    <pottery.colors rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">blue</pottery.colors>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="#pottery.colors">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#DatatypeProperty"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#pottery"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>

<!-- Created with Protege (with OWL Plugin 3.4.8, Build 629)  http://protege.stanford.edu -->
```

The ontology contains a class *pottery*, an instance *pottery_instance_1*, and a datatype property *pottery.colors*.

And I modified these lines in the original code:

```
static final String inputFileName = "pottery.owl";
// ...
ResIterator iter = model.listResourcesWithProperty(pottery.colors);
// ...
System.out.println("  " + iter.nextResource()
                              .getProperty(pottery.colors)
                              .getString());
```

This time I got the error "pottery cannot be resolved to a variable."

What's the trick here? Does it have anything to do with the difference between the formats of the two RDFs? Or something else? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`VCARD`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/VCARD.html) is a java class define in package `com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary`.  It contains Java constants for all the items in the (now, old) VCard vocabulary.

If you want to generate your own class from your ontology, look at the [`schemagen`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/schemagen.html) application shipped with Jena.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! Anyway, before trying schemagen out, I'd like to know if there exists any other way to directly use the properties from my ontology without generating a class. In the schemagen page, I see I can always define a resource using its URL. Any simpler ways? Thanks!